# JS. Clone object but prefix all values

Tags: javascript

Let's say there's an object with string values:

```
const A = { key_a1: "value_a1", key_a2: "value_a2" };
```

What is the way to clone this object and add some prefix to the values? So I want to convert object `A` into object `B` that looks next:

```
const B = { key_a1: "prefix_value_a1", key_a2: "prefix_value_a2" };
```

I know about copy syntax like `const B = { ...A }` but that does not allow to modify values.

Comment: What have you tried? We can probably work out if it's the simplest method.

Comment: something smilar i had https://stackoverflow.com/a/72824860/13583510 except you have to `map` `Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => [k,'prefix_'+v])`

Comment: @Andy well, I should've say that I'm not good in js. I know about copying syntax like `const B = { ...A }` but other then that I'd want to know what my options are. Probably the word "simplest" in the description is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to turn the `keys` and `values` of the original `object` into an array, and `reduce` to create a new Object with the same `keys` of the original object with a prefix.

```js
const A = { key_a1: "value_a1", key_a2: "value_a2" };

const B = Object.entries(A).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc,
    [`prefex_${key}`]: value
  }), {})

console.log(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over it's values, like:

```
Object.values(A).map(i => `prefix_${i}`)
```

Comment: yeah, but this will return the array, not a new object, Probably the answer below is better

Comment: You can construct an object from my answer pretty easily, i just showed how to modify the value :)